# (A&Q)How to speed up RegionMember

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, expression-test

I have to say the `RegionMember` is very slow

```
poly = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}];
SeedRandom[1234];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^4, 2}];
RegionMember[poly, #] & /@ pts // Tr // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {18.1054,5073 False+4927 True}

How to speed up it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also reduce overhead by passing all points at once or by creating a `RegionMemberFunction`:

```
RegionMember[poly, pts] // Tr // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00396, 5073 False + 4927 True}
> ```

```
rm = RegionMember[poly];
rm[pts] // Tr // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.002928, 5073 False + 4927 True}
> ```

```
rm = RegionMember[poly];
rm /@ pts // Tr // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.06013, 5073 False + 4927 True}
> ```

Comment: Thanks,this is good lesson to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a *kernel function*,which will not be abandon and be change arbitrarily in future version *I think*.So I want to share it in here.

### `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ ``

```
poly = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}];
SeedRandom[1234];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^4, 2}];
Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ[poly, #] & /@ pts // 
  Tr // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0582609,5073 False+4927 True}

Comment: @corey979 It always give `False` confusing me still.And it is a *kernel function*,too.